# Proving there exist an interval and a number $p$ where $f(x) \leq x^p$ holds

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, inequality

We have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$, where $f(x)=0$, for $x\leq 0$, and $f$ is a right-continuous function. How can we prove that there exist a number $0 \lt p \leq 1$ and a number $0\lt a$, where:
$$
f(x) \leq x^p,\;\;\;\; for\;\; x\in [0, a].
$$

Comment: What about $\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}$?

Comment: For this function, for example, if we get $p=0.2$, and $a=0.1$, the consequences hold.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Indulge me one more time please: what about $1/\log(1/x)$?

Comment: The range of this function is not $[0,1]$, also the domain is not $\mathbb{R}$. However, if $p=0.1$, and $a=0.1$, then $f(x)\lt x^{0.1}$ for $x \in [0,0.1]$.

Comment: Wlphram alpha says it is not for x=1e-100

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^p} = \infty$ for all $p>0$ so the function proposed by Enredanrestos above has $f(x) > x^p$ for sufficiently small $x$ for all $0<p \leq 1$. As slight variation of the function that is continuous on $[0,1]$ is: $f(x) = \left\{\matrix{\frac{1}{\log(A/x)} & x \in (0,1]\\ 0 & x= 0}\right.$ for any $A>1$.

Comment: You are right. I think this function is a counterexample of above conjecture. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggested this counterexample in the comments. @Winther provided a version continuous in $[0,1]$. The following example is continuous everywhere.
$$ f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1/\log(2/x)& 0<x\ge1\\
0&x\le0\\
1/\log(2) & x>1
\end{cases}$$
Since for all $p>0$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{-x}x^p=0$, by changing variables we can deduce that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\log(2/x)/x^p=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/n}}{2^n}.$$

The series converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ by the Weierstrass M-test. Hence $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is continuous, and $f(0)=0.$ Given $p>0,$ we can choose $1/n<p.$ Then $f(x)/x^p> (1/2^n)x^{1/n-p} \to \infty$ as $x\to 0^+.$